# 3 Way Smart Switches

Tags: electrical

Here is my set-up.

Switch Box 1 - I only have a 3 wire line hooking into this box. There is no two wire line.  But the black wire is hot. The red and the white wires appear to be travelers. There does not appear to be a neutral wire.

Switch Box 2 - There is a two wire line that runs to the lights.  The black wire is not hot and the white wire is bundled up with a bunch of other white wires in the box (Two other switches in the box).  There is a 3 wire line from the first switch. The black line is bundled up with a bunch of other black wires. There are then the red and white traveler wires from the other switch.

What I can't figure out is where the power is coming from.  The Black wire in Switch Box 1 is hot. But I'm guessing it is getting power from Switch Box 2 because it is connected to a bunch of Black wires in that box.

What I'm trying to do is put a 3 way switch in each box. Both are smart switches. None of them are dimmers.  But I can't get it to work no matter how I wire it.

Any recommendations?  Do I need to add a wire to the bundle of black wires in Switch Box 2 and pull in power directly to that switch?

I'm missing a neutral in Switch Box 1, which I think is causing all of this not to work.

Comment: You don't understand how 3-way switches work,  read up more on them.  This is a prerequisite to success even if you are installing smart switches.  If I were you I would roll it back to plain 3-ways until you get more of the hang of this stuff.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all the boxes installed?

Comment: Harper... your comment is not helpful, but thanks for taking the time to post.